# API to refresh token in interceptor is executed too many times

Tags: angular, refresh-token, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using a interceptor in Angular to refresh token 10 minutes before this expires, but when I called the API to refresh the token, this API is called too many times.

This is my code

```
constructor(
    private store: Store,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    const token = this.store.snapshot().auth.selectedToken;
    if (token) {
      const decodedToken: any = jwt_decode(token);
      //Se verifica que al token le queden 10 minutos o menos para actualizarlo
      const expirationTime = 28 * 60 * 1000;
      const expirationDate: any = new Date(decodedToken.exp * 1000);
      const currentTime = new Date();
      const shouldRefreshToken = expirationDate.getTime() - currentTime.getTime() < expirationTime;

      if (shouldRefreshToken) {
        const url = AppConfig.API_ENDPOINT;
        const email = this.store.snapshot().auth.email;
        const token = this.store.snapshot().auth.azureToken;
        const refresh = this.store.snapshot().auth.refresh;
        const user = this.store.snapshot().auth.user;
        this.http.post(`${url}/refresh_session`, { email, token, refresh }).subscribe({
          next: (res: any) => {
            console.log(res);
            this.authService.storeSession(res.app_token, email, user, res.azure_token.token,    res.azure_token.refresh);
            const clonedRequest = request.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${res.app_token}`
              }
            });
            return next.handle(clonedRequest);
          },
          error: (err: any) => {/**/}
        });
      }
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

I tried with pipe instead of subscribe but it's not works.